# Show the coefficients of power series are the same?

Tags: real-analysis

How to show the coefficients of power series are the same for two power series that coincide on an interval. I first thought about using $x=0$ to prove $a_0=b_0$ and using $n$th derivatives to show $a_n=b_n.$ But I realized that $0$ is not necessary in the interval of coincidence. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: can't you do the same, but consider a power series expanded about $x_0$, and consider the function and all derivatives at $x=x_0$.

Comment: I guess the question is like this.  Suppose two power series centered at zero have radii of convergence ${}\ge 4$, and the values of the two series coincide on the interval $(3,4)$.  Show that the coefficients of the two power series agree.  A deleted answer used complex analysis for this.  Is there a more elementary way?

Comment: That is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Power series are defined for other values than $0$, so as long as you do the expansion around $x_0$ in the interior of your interval (not on the boundary), it will work.

The theorems are then the same, and you can use the relation between $n$-th derivative and $n$-th coefficient to conclude, as you suggested.